# Script block in XSL not being rendered

Tags: javascript, xslt, scripting

I can't get a `<script></script>` block in my XSL template to be rendered. It is simply being ignored by the parser, the block itself and anything inside it. By the way, I am using the DotNetNuke report module. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an xss prevention measure, try if you can turn off automatic tag escaping if there is an option like that.

Comment: You are right, I found the tool removes the script tags because they could be potentially dangerous. Thanks.